# How can I show some text on a textbox in a user control by clicking a button in another user control?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

please be kind enough to note that I'm new to visual studio.I have a form named form1 in it I have 2 user controls namely uctxt and ucbtn. uctxt has a textbox named txt1 and ucbtn has a button named btn1.
I need to fill txt1 with some text by clicking btn1(I tried public modifiers). I searched everywhere on the internet for a solution for this and I found nothing.

I tried:

```
public void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            uctxt ucText = new uctxt();
            ucText.txt1.Text = "welcome";
        }
```

Comment: It is pretty easy to implement. You need to do some more research. Long story short - you need a way to set a `uctxt.txt1.Text` value from a public member of your `uctxt` (public property or method) and a public event on your `ucbtn` which is rises on `ucbtn.btn1.Click` event rised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least to expose the `OnClick` event on the `ucbtn`:

```
public event EventHandler UserControlButtonClick;

protected void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) =>     
    if (this.UserControlButtonClick != null)
        this.UserControlButtonClick(this, e);
```

And the label on the `uctxt`:

```
public String UserControlLabelText
{
    get{return txt1.Text;}
    set{txt1.Text = value;}
}
```

After that you can use them both from the main form like this:

```
ucbtn1.UserControlButtonClick += new EventHandler(ucbtn1_ButtonClick);

protected void ucbtn1_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    uctxt1.UserControlLabelText = "your text";
}
```

Comment: I created an Object uctxt inside OnClick event to give refference to txt1,it did't work the code is.. private void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            uctxt ucText = new uctxt();
            ucText.txt1.Text = "welcome";
        }

Comment: thanks @Giulio Caccin, ucbtn1.UserControlButtonClick += new EventHandler(ucbtn1_ButtonClick); what is ucbtn1 here?

Comment: @jzen when i used numbers i mean an actual instance of one of your user controls. It means, if you have a user control, once you drag it inside the main form, visual studio create an automatic id for the dropped control and usually it calls it with the `name + number`. If you think it's the answer mark it as such.